# One Table, Two GridViews ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am wondering if it is possible to migrate data in a table from gridview to another! Meaning If I have a table called Products, for example. How can I show data in a gridview when pressing the Search button. And then I can select only one row at a time. Once selecting the required row, then I can press a button which sends this row to another gridview for Editing, Deleting, or Updating!
Is it Possible at some point! I know VERY WELL, that this method can be done using one Grid, But I mainly ask if it is possible this can be done on two grids?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is No need for two grids

Comment: It can be done, but its not really user-friendly nor logical to do so in my opinion... You could show the row in some textboxes or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `onselect`. When the user select a product, you make the gridview containing the list of product invisible (`gv.visibled=false`). On the same method get the data of the selected row before making it invisble. Once you get it, bind it to the gridview.

Comment: Sounds complicated, but it makes sense!